# Is it possible to find these eigenvalues manually?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So i was given this system to convert to a matrix and then input to a program to find the eigenvalues which was easy enough. I was then asked to find the manual steps of doing so however this cubic characteristic equation is incredibly unfeasible to solve for $\lambda$ while i know how to do long division which is not taught in this non-math course i am still unable to solve it.

The equation given are 
$$2X+5Y+Z=1$$ $$  X-2Y+3Z=3$$ $$Y-5Z=2 $$

Which of course converts to a coefficient matrix...
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2&5&1\\
1&-2&3\\
0&1&-5&\end{bmatrix}$$

which after cofactor expansion os $A-\lambda I$ i found the characteristic equation
$$-\lambda^3+5\lambda^2+12\lambda+40 $$

The application came out with eigen values:
$$\lambda_1=3.0865 \qquad \lambda_2=-2.205 \qquad \lambda_3=-5.8841 $$

Which wolfram alpha also verifies

However in terms of doing this question manually the task becomes way too unfeasible in the scope of the course and what was actually thought (btw this guy introduced matrices and eigenvalues in the same lecture and it's not even a math course lol).

Which makes me think i've made a really big mistake.

Comment: Well, at least [cubic polynomials are solvable in surd forms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html), so at least in theory, you can solve it manually.

Comment: Lol but how would i go about doing this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to find the eigenvalues? It seems that the question only asks you to solve the system of three linear equations. You don't need eigenvalues to do that.

Comment: Nah i didn't post the actual question, it specifically asks for eigenvalues and the determinant

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a misprint. Should the $(2,2)$-th entry be $2$ instead of $-2$, the characteristic polynomial would be $\lambda(\lambda^2+\lambda-24)$, which is easily solvable by hand. And since the matrix becomes singular, it's more interesting to find all feasible solutions.

If it's not a misprint, then congratulations. You must be an elite enrolled at a top college and your instructor does expect you to know how to solve a cubic polynomial with muscle memory.

Answer (score 1):

For polynomials up to degree $4$, there are formulae to find the roots. In your case, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function) should be useful.

Comment: Wait how do you use this and which one?

Comment: @kingportable Look at the formula $C=\ldots$ in "general formula for roots".

Comment: C is inconclusive was i wrong to get $\Delta_1$=61 and $\Delta_2$=817?

Comment: oh $\Delta_2 = 1870$ which works

Comment: @kingportable :)

Comment: What am i suppose to plug this in to $\frac{1}{3a} \sqrt[3]{b+u_kC+\frac{\Delta_0}{u_kC}}$ but some values of $u_k$ have imaginary numbers

Comment: @kingportable Yes, but if the solutions are real, all of the imaginary parts will cancel out.

Comment: Did i do something wrong? I got a 7 for the $u_k=1$ $u_k=1$ which doesn't match any of my values  http://imgur.com/yh9jQMA